# Read xml string and getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to read xml string from DB. However my code is erroring?

Here is my code

```
string strUrl = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><boolean>false</boolean>";

XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(strUrl)); 

while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element: 
            break;

        case XmlNodeType.Text: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Where I'm i going wrong?

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: could you please post error also

Comment: sorry im i bad.. fixed it.. new StringReader(strUrl)

Comment: @user929153, Please, next time correct your question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code as is won't compile, because you use double quotes inside the string. You could try to use single quotes instead:

```
string strUrl = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?><boolean>false</boolean>";
```

Alternatively escape the double quotes:

```
string strUrl = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><boolean>false</boolean>";
```

Comment: Option 1 above will not compile - you still need to escape the internal quotes as per option 2 `\"`.

Comment: Your first code also won't compile. The correct one is `string strUrl = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?><boolean>false</boolean>";`